# Get UIWebView to scroll and bounce horizontally but not vertically

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an iphone UIWebView with contents that are approx 1000px x 200px. Currently when scrolling with your finger, it'll bounce vertically but not horizontally.

I want it to do the opposite: bounce horizontally but not vertically.

Is there some trickery i need to do in my html to achieve this? Eg setting the width and height on the body explicitly maybe? Or is it a setting of the UIWebView? I can do  the following to totally disable bouncing, is there something similar to set bouncing on a per-direction basis?

```
[[[webView subviews] lastObject] setBounces:NO];
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 5, you don't need to access the subviews. `UIWebView` contains a `scrollView` property to the nested UIScrollView:

To disable bounce:

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

To only bounce vertically:

```
webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
```

Comment: In the WKWebview, the webview.scrollView.bounces should be set to YES.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a CSS StyleSheet and set the a container Div with the dimension of your view. and apply the styleSheet to your UIWebView.

You can do it like that -

```
NSString *cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];

        //do base url for css
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        NSString *html =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\"  href=\"%@\" type=\"text/css\" /></head><body><section></section><br><br></body></html>",,cssPath];
        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle through all the UIWebViews subviews(using a for loop) checking each one to see if it's a UIscrollView (using `isMemberOfClass:`) and then change the properties in the UIScrollView to meet your needs.

```
for (UIView *subview in [myWebView subviews]) {
    if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        [(UIScrollView *)subview setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
        [(UIScrollView *)subview setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i saw those properties and gave them a try but it didn't help.

Comment: instead of `isMemberOfClass` try `isKindOfClass`

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.webView subviews]) {
    SEL sel = @selector(setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:);
    if( [subview respondsToSelector:sel] ){
        [subview performSelector:sel withObject:(id)YES];
    }
}
```

in your viewDidLoad